# Is it possible to block certain method calls to a member variable of a class

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone

I require to create a Camera class on top of the default camera class for Windows Phone 8, [PhotoCaptureDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.photocapturedevice%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Ideally I would have wanted to build a child class

```
class CustomCaptureDevice:PhotoCaptureDevice{
    ....
    ....
}
```

This would have allowed me to both configure the camera device, and also provide for some additional frame processing technique via CustomCaptureDevice. Unfortunately, `PhotoCaptureDevice` is a `sealed class`, hence I cannot do that.

Now I can think of two alternative methods which could help me tackle the problem:

(1)

```
class CustomCaptureDevice
{
    private PhotoCaptureDevice captureDevice;

    // Implement all the functions of PhotoCaptureDevice here. And internally redirect them to PhotoCaptureDevice

}
```

The above method would be too cumbersome. And in case of any API changes to PhotoCaptureDevice, could require significant updates to CustomCaptureDevice class.

(2)

```
class CustomCaptureDevice
{
    public PhotoCaptureDevice captureDevice;

    // Expose this variable to the user, who can set things in PhotoCaptureDevice as per his needs.

}
```

The above seems to be an easier solution, since it would require minimal updates in case of API changes to PhotoCaptureDevice.

It seems (2) could fit my requirement well. But I have an additional requirement, because of which (2) could prove unfit. I want to disable certain configuration capabilities in PhotoCaptureDevice, since I want to keep a few parameters like exposure and focus not configurable by the user.

How could I accomplish this in the design framework of (2). Is it possible at all?

I understand that it would be easy to implement by approach (1). Please take note of the constraint that `PhotoCaptureDevice` is a **sealed class**.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is usually called the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) (i.e. a wrapper). I believe that this is exactly the thing you need, as it allows you to provide any functionality for the given interface under the hood.

To make the class interchangeable with a `PhotoCaptureDevice` in other parts of your app, you will have to implement its relevant interfaces:

```
public class ExtendedPhotoCaptureDevice : IDisposable, ICameraCaptureDevice
{
    private readonly ICameraCaptureDevice _actualImplementation;
    ...
}
```

Comment: My fear with (1) was that I might have to write each method of PhotoCaptureDevice inside ExtendedPhotoCaptureDevice . Meaning something like     

`class ExtendedPhotoCaptureDevice {
    private PhotoCaptureDevice actualCaptureDevice;

    OpenAsync()
    {
         actualCaptureDevice.OpenAsync();
    }
}`

Here, I do not need to modify behaviour of `OpenSync()` function.
Can rewriting unmodified methods be avoided using decorator pattern? Thanks...

Comment: Btw, I suppose you missed the main constraint I am working with. Here PhotoCaptureDevice is a `sealed class`. Hence, I got the following error while trying to use your approach: `Error 1 'ExtendedPhotoCaptureDevice': cannot derive from sealed type 'Windows.Phone.Media.Capture.PhotoCaptureDevice'`

Comment: Well, you can try using dynamics to create a proxy (e.g. [this article](http://brianbacon.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/dynamic-proxy-or-getting-crazy-with-dynamics-and-expressions/)), but it all depends on how you're planning to use it. And I am not inheriting from `PhotoCaptureDevice`, I just stated it should implement the `ICameraCaptureDevice` interface.

Comment: I understand your point now. `ICameraCaptureDevice` is actually not a **sealed class**, and infact `PhotoCaptureDevice` inherits from it. But I would prefer to be using `PhotoCaptureDevice` since it has some useful extra methods on top of `ICameraCaptureDevice`. And so m still looking for the best solution possible while using `PhotoCaptureDevice`. I will check if proxy proves to be useful for me. Thanks..

Comment: Well, since `PhotoCaptureDevice` is sealed, you won't be able to use your class as a true replacement. Unless you access it through the interface, it's irrelevant which methods you will choose to proxy (and they don't even need to have the same name, unless your code uses dynamics all over the place).